# When my code not exiting while loop in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements, nested-loops

It's a black jack game project. When user_score > 21  or 21 , it shold exit the while loop but it is not exiting while loop.I am new in coding. Plese tell me where is the problem.

I don't want to use break command. Because from which tutorial I am learning she has not taught me it yet.

You can get an idea of black jack game here.[247blackjack](https://www.247blackjack.com/)

I tried these lines of code.

```
import random
def deal_card():    
    cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    random_index = random.randint(0,(len(cards)-1))
    random_card = cards[random_index]
    return random_card

def want_another_card():
    want_card = input("Want another card type 'y' for yes and type 'n' for no.")
    return want_card
user_card = []
computer_card = []

for x in range(0,2):
    user_card.append(deal_card())
    computer_card.append(deal_card())

def calculate_score(list):
    score = sum(list)
    return score

user_score = calculate_score(user_card)
computer_score =calculate_score(computer_card)
#final score function
def final_score_calculation():
    while calculate_score(computer_card)< 17:
        computer_card.append(deal_card())
    
    line_gap()
    print(f"Your final hand: {user_card}, final score: {user_score}")
    print(f"Computer's final hand: {computer_card}, final score: {computer_score}")
    
    if user_score > computer_score and user_score < 21:
        winner = "User"
        print(f"{winner} wins")
    elif computer_score > user_score and computer_score < 21:
        winner = "computer"
        print(f"{winner} wins")
    elif computer_score > 21:
        print("Computer busted. You win.")
    elif user_score > 21:
        print("User busted, Computer wins")
    elif user_score == 21:
        print("user wins")
    elif computer_score == 21:
        print("computer wins")
    elif computer_score == user_score:
        print("It's a draw")


should_continue = True
while should_continue == True:
    print(f"Your cards: {user_card}, current score {calculate_score(user_card)}")
    print(f"computer's first card {computer_card[0]}")


    #checking if user or computer has a black jack
    if user_score == 21 and len(user_card) == 2:
        print("User has the blackJack. You win")
        should_continue = False
    elif computer_score ==21 and len(computer_card) == 2:
        print("Computer has the black jack .You lose")
        should_continue = False
    #checking if they got busted or got 21
    if user_score > 21:   #checking user

        if 11 in user_card:
            usr_indx_pos=user_card.index(11) 
            user_card[usr_indx_pos] = 1
            if user_score > 21:
                print("you got busted.You lose.")
                should_continue = False
            
            elif user_score ==21:
                print("you have 21 . you win")
                should_continue = False
        else:
            print("you got busted.You lose.")
            should_continue = False


    elif computer_score > 21:     #checking computer
        if 11 in computer_card:
            com_indx_pos = computer_card.index(11)
            computer_card[com_indx_pos] = 1
            if computer_score > 21:
                print("computer busted. you win")
                should_continue = False
        else:
            print("computer got busted. You win")
            should_continue = False
    elif user_score ==21:
        print("you win. you got 21")
        should_continue = False
    elif computer_score ==21:
        print("computer win. computer got 21")
        should_continue = False
    
    line_gap()
    if want_another_card() == "y":
        user_card.append(deal_card())
        user_score = calculate_score(user_card)
    else:
        final_score_calculation()
        should_continue = False
```

Comment: Where is the code that changes the computers score?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your complaint is that it is prompting you if you want another card even after you bust (or win), the solution is to ensure you don't issue that prompt when the loop is supposed to be done anyway. Just change:

```
if want_another_card() == "y":
```

to:

```
if should_continue and want_another_card() == "y":
```

This will cause it to do the `final_score_calculation()` call in the `else`, which may be redundant; if it shouldn't report the results again when someone has already busted or got exactly 21, wrap the whole of:

```
if want_another_card() == "y":
    user_card.append(deal_card())
    user_score = calculate_score(user_card)
else:
    final_score_calculation()
    should_continue = False
```

in a check to see if it already knows it's done, making it:

```
if should_continue:
    if want_another_card() == "y":
        user_card.append(deal_card())
        user_score = calculate_score(user_card)
    else:
        final_score_calculation()
        should_continue = False
```

so it does no additional work when it already knows the game is over.